# Set response header and request header for cross domain file upload

Tags: javascript, php, xmlhttprequest, cross-domain

I'm trying to upload a file from localhost:8888 to www.base.com . When the upload starts I have this error

```
Cross-Origin Request Blocked: The Same Origin Policy disallows reading the remote 
resource at http://base.com/public_upload. (Reason: missing token 'x-file-name' 
in CORS header 'Access-Control-Allow-Headers' from CORS preflight channel).
```

Here are the header responses from php server that I set

```
header('Access-Control-Allow-Origin: http://localhost:8888');
header("Access-Control-Allow-Methods: GET, POST, OPTIONS, PUT, DELETE");
header("Access-Control-Allow-Headers: Origin, X-Requested-With, Content-Type, Accept");
```

And here is the request header in upload script which runs in browser hosted by localhost:8888

```
xhr.setRequestHeader("Content-Type", "multipart/form-data"); 
xhr.setRequestHeader("X-File-Name", unescape(encodeURIComponent(file.name)));
xhr.setRequestHeader("X-File-Size", file.size);
xhr.setRequestHeader("X-File-Type", file.type);
```

What headers I've could mis-configed to create such error message?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to add `X-File-Name`, `X-File-Size` and `X-File-Type` to the list of headers:

```
header("Access-Control-Allow-Headers: Origin, X-Requested-With, Content-Type, Accept, X-File-Name, X-File-Size, X-File-Type");
```

Removing the `Access-Control-Allow-Headers` header should work too.